# Trying to understand nature of hacking

Tags: security

Today we saw suddenly two files created in root folder in one of our wordpress websites - file name `owp.php` and `gmail.html`

On investigating the access logs following entries were found which seem to be malicious and similar to time in which this files were created.

```
91.207.9.226 - - [23/Apr/2013:17:41:19 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 19928 "http://remont-mobile-phones.ru/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; ru) Opera 8.01"
91.207.9.226 - - [23/Apr/2013:17:41:21 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 19928 "http://remont-mobile-phones.ru/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; ru) Opera 8.01"
```

Can anyone help in understanding the nature of attack and suggestive actions to be taken now.

Comment: Start with WordPress's own "So You've Been Hacked" article: http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Comment: I have already taken all such steps. Just trying to understand the log entry

Comment: Check your .htaccess

Comment: htaccess is clean. nothing other than normal code found

Comment: thanks s_ha_dum. I was unaware about such standards. Got all the details from advanced help section now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is using [Apache's Combined Log Format](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#combined).  So here's what's actually *in* your logfile lines:

```
91.207.9.226 {Remote client's IP address}
- {Remote user ID, generally unused}
- {Authenticated user ID, unused in most cases}
[23/Apr/2013:17:41:19 +0530] {Date}
"GET / HTTP/1.1" {Request - here they asked for your site's home page, essentially}
200 {Status code -- 200 = Success}
19928 {Transferred data -- your homepage is 19928 bytes}
"http://remont-mobile-phones.ru/" {Referer}
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; ru) Opera 8.01" {User-agent / browser}
```

It appears that someone (or some 'bot, or other software) at IP `91.207.9.226` clicked on a link to `http://[your site]/` on the site at `http://remont-mobile-phones.ru/`.

These two entries look pretty innocent to my eyes -- though I will admit I'm not an expert.  Is there anything around the same time in your access or error logs?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the log format. this entries were found in access logs, no other entries found. Also, couldn't find anything relevant in the error log : Just  the following entry  : "PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'XCache' because conflicting module 'eAccelerator' is already loaded in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: Is it possible the files were placed there by some other method?  FTP, SFTP, etc.?